# *insert word here* cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I am doing a project for school and can not seem to find the reason for this error. I am very new to programming and appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Lemonade {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lemons_per_pitcher = 12;
    int spoons_per_bag = 1000;
    int spoons_per_pitcher = 50;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of lemons you have.");
    int lemon = user.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of bags of sugar you have.");
    int bags = user.nextInt();
    int spoons = bags * 1000;
    int sugar = spoons / 50;
    int lemons2 = lemon / 12;
    if( lemons2 > sugar){
        int pitcher = lemons2;
    }else{
        int pitcher = sugar;
    }
    if( lemon < 12 || bags < 1){
        System.out.println("You can make a maximum of 0 pitchers");
    } else{
        System.out.println("This is the maximum amount of pitchers you can         make is: " + pitcher);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is no tthat spaced to the left in my program btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pitcher` is a local value so you can define it in main method.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pitcher;
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lemons_per_pitcher = 12;
        int spoons_per_bag = 1000;
        int spoons_per_pitcher = 50;
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of lemons you have.");
        int lemon = user.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of bags of sugar you have.");
        int bags = user.nextInt();
        int spoons = bags * 1000;
        int sugar = spoons / 50;
        int lemons2 = lemon / 12;
        if (lemons2 > sugar) {
            pitcher = lemons2;
        } else {
            pitcher = sugar;
        }
        if (lemon < 12 || bags < 1) {
            System.out.println("You can make a maximum of 0 pitchers");
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("This is the maximum amount of pitchers you can         make is: "
                            + pitcher);
        }
    }
```

**You can use a variable only in the block where you defined it.**

For instance:

```
{
    int i = 0;
}
i++; // ERROR : There no i in this block
```

In you code:

```
if( lemons2 > sugar){
    int pitcher = lemons2;
}else{
    int pitcher = sugar;
} // pitcher no more exists after block
```

Comment: I am very new to this and exactly know what a "local" variable is, specifics appreciated.

Comment: oh ok I understand now. How do I go aboout correcting it then while keeping it assigned to the if-statement

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with these conditionals:

```
if( lemons2 > sugar){
    int pitcher = lemons2;
}else{
    int pitcher = sugar;
}
```

When you declare pitcher you are limiting its scope to only within the immediate brackets. Meaning that the only place you can use the variable pitcher is:

```
if( lemons2 > sugar){
    int pitcher = lemons2; //Here
}else{
    int pitcher = sugar; //And here
}
```

Calling it anywhere else will give you an error.

What you should do is declare pitcher right above the first conditional as such:

```
int pitcher = 0;
if( lemons2 > sugar){
    pitcher = lemons2;
}else{
    pitcher = sugar;
}
```